# Захват содержимого формы до ее отправки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дано:
Страница корзины товаров, в ней форма "Имя" "Телефон" "Email"

Задача:
Сохранять содержимое формы даже если не была нажата кнопка оформления заказа.
Сохранять только те поля, где заполнен хоть один символ.

Пример: Человек добавил товар в корзину и перешел в нее, заполнил имя и телефон и закрыл окно браузера. Нужно, чтобы имя и телефон где-то сохранились.** *Где - неважно пока - как пример возьмем .txt файл в корне.***

txt, видимо, плохой пример.
Давайте, конкретизируем: Пользователь кликает по полю input, вводит туда >0 символов, далее кликает куда либо вне этого поля, в этот момент символы которые были в поле должны сохраняться в любое доступное мне место.

Update:

Коллеги, у меня вопрос не как пользователю сохранить куки с введенной информацией, а как мне, как админу сайта получить содержимое заполненных полей, если форма не была отправлена нажатием кнопки "Оформить заказ".
Или принудительно данные копировать из этой формы в какую-то скрытую и отправлять ее в какой-то обработчик, либо фиксировать изменения текста в полях как-то.

Comment: .txt файл в корне чего? Нельзя просто взять и записать из браузера в файл данные. Сохранять можно, например, в localStorage при изменении значений input-ов.

Comment: upd: если нужно отправить данные, это можно сделать прямо в блоке сохранения кукис. Я дописал в свой ответ код отправки данных, и самый простейший пример сохранения отправленного пакета в файл на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сохранить значения в cookie на 1 неделю, и при последующих загрузках страницы снова заполнять поля прошлыми значениями

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input class='catching_input' name='Name' id='name' placeholder='Имя'>
<input class='catching_input'name='Phone' id='phone' placeholder='Телефон'>
<input class='catching_input'name='Email' id='email' placeholder='E-mail'>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.catching_input').on('change',function() {
  var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var input_value = $(this).val();
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));
  document.cookie = input_id + "="+input_value+"; expires="+d.toGMTString()+"; path=/";

  var url = "user_data_collect.php";

    var packet = $(".catching_input").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: packet,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Для тестирования, потом убрать
      }
  });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.catching_input').each(function(){
        var prev_val = getCookie($(this).attr('id'));
      if (prev_val) {
        $(this).val(prev_val);
      }

    })
});

function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $row = "\r\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $row .= $key.":".$value." | ";
    }
    $fp = fopen("user_data.log", "a");
    $write = fwrite($fp, serialize($row)); 
    fclose($fp);
    echo "[]";
?>
```

[Запустить пример](https://jsfiddle.net/y1e79zm6/31/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранять данные в localStorage при изменении значений input-ов. А при загрузке страницы, например, подставлять сохранённые значения:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  Имя: <input name="name"/>
  Телефон: <input name="phone"/>
  Email: <input name="email"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var $formInputs = $("#form input");

  $formInputs.each(function() {
    this.value = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr("name"));
  });

  $formInputs.on("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("name"), this.value);
  });
});
```

[Полный пример в JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79m06z35/3/)