# Срабатывание скрипта один раз за заданный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например на странице имеется объект при наведении на который появляется попап, как сделать, чтобы его вызов был возможен только один раз в 10 минут.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону localstorage или cookies?

Comment: При наведении, просто создайте куку с mktime на 10 минут и при каждом наведении сверяйте время куки и реальное время.

Comment: @Arsen спасибо, хороший совет, но к сожалению только разбираюсь в js и еще не работал с куками и как я понял mktime это функция php. Если не сложно, можно привести небольшой пример или ссылку где можно почитать, буду разбираться.

Comment: @kost1k например, [недавно был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/802931/183458). Один из ответов - сохранение данных с помощью cookies, другой - с помощью localStorage. Нужно лишь адаптировать сохранение и загрузку под ваши нужды.

Comment: А если пользователь перегрузил старицу, то эти 10 минут продолжаться должны или скидываться?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин продолжаться

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример, надо протестировать, написал на скорую руку )։

```
   function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
        var today = new Date();
        var expire = new Date();
        if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)
            nDays = 1;
        expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
        document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) +
            ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() +
            ";path=/";

    }


    function getCookie(c_name) {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }

var current = new Date();


    /*Получаем куку*/
    var check = getCookie('hover');

    /*mktime*/
    var mktime = current.getTime();

    /*Для сверки прибавляем 10 минут - 600 секунд*/
    var after10min = mktime + parseInt(600);

   if(check){ 
    if (check > after10min) {
        console.log('Делаем наведение');

        /*Вставляем новую куку*/
        setCookie('hover', seconds, 1);
    } else {
        console.log('10 минут пока не прошло');
    }
   } else{
        console.log('Делаем наведение');

        /*Вставляем новую куку*/
        setCookie('hover', seconds, 1);

   }
```

Comment: Сложновато пока для моего восприятия, но теоретически я понял что мне нужно и возможно мой вариант будет даже попроще. Вот что надумал: при наведении на объект я проверяю наличие куки, если нет то показываю попап и создаю куку на 10 минут. Может в твоем ответе это и описано, но я немного по другому понял( Как проверить наличие конкретной куки?

Comment: @kost1k именно это я и показал в примере :) там же в комментариях я расписал что и как

Comment: Прошу прощения за мою назойливость, но очень хочется разобраться)

Comment: @kost1k я привёл детальный пример, что не понятно там ? ))

Comment: Как я понимаю твой код. Первая функция служит для создания куки, вторая возвращает нам параметр времени куки с заданным именем (вот кстати unescape уже не рекомендуют использовать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape). Дальше переменная after10min которая отсчитывает 10 минут, вроде время в миллисекундах считается, почему мы тогда 600 прибавляем? Дальше идет проверка, если есть такая кука и ее время больше 10 минут то срабатывает наведение и создается новая кука на 1 день.

Comment: И при проверке получается, что данной куки у нас еще нет и ни чего не срабатывает.

Comment: Вы хоть пробовали тестровать мой пример, или так, на взгляд оцениваете работу  логики ??

Comment: Конечно пробовал, по этому и пытаюсь разобраться как это должно работать)

Comment: Консоль жалуется что не может определить год в переменной second и в after10min соответственно

Comment: Обновил код, сделал более понятным (изменил логику mktime).

Comment: @Aresen проблема связанная с временем исчезла, но работает так как и я предполагал выше, каждый раз при наведении выводит в консоль что 10 минут еще не прошло, т.к. кука не создана, а условие для ее создания не срабатывает так ее нету)

Comment: Я понимаю что с javascript вы ещё на ВЫ, но вроде уже начинаете понимать логику, старайтесь сами подумать что надо было бы сделать если куки нет - установить )). Обновил ответ, проверяйте

Comment: Да, с js'ом только знакомлюсь) Теперь как я понял не срабатывает условие проверки куки и при каждом наведении отображает и заново создается кука. Еще не пойму зачем делать столько проверок? Разве не проще просто создавать куку не на 1 день, а на 10 минут и просто проверять ее наличие?

Comment: Да конечно можно создать на 10 мин куку, просто так могут быть погрешности + - минута, две